# How to call data from firebase

Tags: javascript, reactjs, firebase, next.js, stack-overflow

why i cant see any data in my [projectId] page  and i already have data in my firebase firestore
this the firebase architicture :
/users/userID/projects/projectID/etages/etageID/appartements/apparetmntsID
the normal approche is that the user get to see the project data as he clcik on the projectId link
index page:

```
    import { getProjectIds } from '../../lib/getProjectIds';
import Link from 'next/link'

function Admin({ projectIds }) {
  return (
    <div>
      <h1>Admin Dashboard</h1>
      <p>Projects for user:</p>
      <ul>
        {projectIds.map((id) => (
          <Link href={`/admin/${id}`}>
              <li key={id}>{id}</li>
          </Link>
          
        ))}
      </ul>
    </div>
  );
}

export async function getStaticProps() {
  const userId = "QHSLdaXniIgFOv7QXBQOk99Hknj1"; // Replace with the actual user ID
  const projectIds = await getProjectIds(userId);

  return {
    props: {
      projectIds,
    },
  };
}

export default Admin;
[projectId].js:import React, { useState, useEffect } from 'react';
import { useRouter } from 'next/router';
import getProjectDetails from '../../lib/getProjectDetails';

function ProjectsDetails() {
  const router = useRouter();
  const projectId = router.query.projectId;

  useEffect(() => {
    const fetchProjectDetails = async () => {
      try {
        const details = await getProjectDetails(projectId);
        console.log(details);
      } catch (error) {
        console.error("Error retrieving project details:", error);
      }
    };

    if (projectId) {
      fetchProjectDetails();
    }
  }, [projectId]);

  return (
    <div>
          <p>Projects for user: {projectId}</p>
          <ul></ul>
        </div>
      );

}

export default ProjectsDetails;
getProjectDetails function:                                                                                                                                                              import { collection, doc, getDocs, getDoc, query, where } from "firebase/firestore";
import { db } from "../config/firebase";

async function getProjectDetails(projectId) {
  try {
    // Get the etages
    const etagesQuerySnapshot = await getDocs(collection(db, "projects", projectId, "etages"));
    const etages = [];

    for (const etageDoc of etagesQuerySnapshot.docs) {
      const etageData = etageDoc.data();
      const etageId = etageDoc.id;

      // Get the apartments for the etage
      const apartmentsQuerySnapshot = await getDocs(collection(etageDoc.ref, "appartements"));
      const apartments = [];

      for (const apartmentDoc of apartmentsQuerySnapshot.docs) {
        const apartmentData = apartmentDoc.data();
        const apartmentId = apartmentDoc.id;

        // Get the doors for the apartment
        const doorsQuerySnapshot = await getDocs(collection(apartmentDoc.ref, "Doors"));
        const doors = [];

        for (const doorDoc of doorsQuerySnapshot.docs) {
          const doorData = doorDoc.data();
          doors.push({
            id: doorDoc.id,
            // Include other door details you want to retrieve
            // Example: width: doorData.width, height: doorData.height, etc.
          });
        }

        // Get the placard for the apartment
        const placardDoc = await getDoc(collection(apartmentDoc.ref, "placard"));
        const placardData = placardDoc.data();

        apartments.push({
          id: apartmentId,
          // Include other apartment details you want to retrieve
          // Example: name: apartmentData.name, size: apartmentData.size, etc.
          doors,
          placard: placardData,
        });
      }

      etages.push({
        id: etageId,
        // Include other etage details you want to retrieve
        // Example: number: etageData.number, etc.
        apartments,
      });
    }

    return etages;
  } catch (error) {
    console.error("Error retrieving project details:", error);
    throw error;
  }
}

export default getProjectDetails;
```